# Unable to restart networking service

Tags: networking

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 server

```
[root@wspbm]# uname -a
Linux wspbm 4.4.0-131-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On boot, this machine comes up with all of the networking that is expected to be in place.  Restarting networking says all of the interfaces are unknown.

Dmesg output shows that the interfaces get renamed at boot and the interfaces file references those new names.  Yet all of the error messages state that the interfaces are unknown.  The goal here is just to be able to restart the networking service without error.  Happy to provide any additional details.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

ip add output:

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:85:64:76:33:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::d685:64ff:fe76:337a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br_parental state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:85:64:76:33:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::d685:64ff:fe76:337c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp4s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:85:64:76:33:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:85:64:76:33:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:85:64:76:33:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.17/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d685:64ff:fe76:337a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br_parental: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:85:64:76:33:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.1/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global br_parental
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d685:64ff:fe76:337c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:14:06:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.5/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global br1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20ac:ff:fe77:5264/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: br-252fbfc5e3eb: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:25:62:de:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 scope global br-252fbfc5e3eb
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ec:d9:07:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:ecff:fed9:70a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: veth9bc939a@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether e2:19:05:d2:13:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::e019:5ff:fed2:13f6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:20:6c:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:20:6c:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:52:92:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe52:9286/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:1e:29:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe1e:29a4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:14:06:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe14:6b4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

/etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# Configure the primary network interface
# This is the interface facing the internet
# and is in the br0 bridge
auto enp3s0f0

# Configure the interface facing the kid's router
# This is the interface on ingress which has unfiltered 
# traffic and is in the br_parental bridge
auto enp3s0f1

# Configure the other two interfaces to try and avoid errors
auto enp4s0f0
auto enp4s0f1

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports enp3s0f0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0


auto br_parental
iface br_parental inet static
    address 192.168.5.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports enp3s0f1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

dmesg output:

```
[root@wspbm]# dmesg | grep enp 
[    3.156327] bnx2 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: renamed from eth1
[    3.726740] bnx2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: renamed from eth0
[    3.811065] bnx2 0000:04:00.1 enp4s0f1: renamed from eth3
[    3.854786] bnx2 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: renamed from eth2
[   10.707562] device enp3s0f0 entered promiscuous mode
[   10.707743] device enp3s0f1 entered promiscuous mode
[   11.031815] bnx2 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: using MSIX
[   11.031850] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f1: link is not ready
[   11.099798] bnx2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: using MSIX
[   11.099826] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f0: link is not ready
[   14.221725] bnx2 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[   14.221826] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0f1: link becomes ready
[   14.221873] br_parental: port 1(enp3s0f1) entered forwarding state
[   14.221885] br_parental: port 1(enp3s0f1) entered forwarding state
[   14.772048] bnx2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0f0: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[   14.772148] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0f0: link becomes ready
[   14.772187] br0: port 1(enp3s0f0) entered forwarding state
[   14.772199] br0: port 1(enp3s0f0) entered forwarding state
```

service networking restart output:

```
[root@wspbm]# service networking restart
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@wspbm]#
```

systemctl status networking.service output:

```
    ● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-08-08 08:37:41 MDT; 2min 31s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 16185 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16179 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16185 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm ifup[16185]: Unknown interface enp4s0f0
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm ifup[16185]: Unknown interface enp4s0f1
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm ifup[16185]: Unknown interface enp3s0f0
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm ifup[16185]: Unknown interface enp3s0f1
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm ifup[16185]: Unknown interface enp4s0f0
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm ifup[16185]: Unknown interface enp4s0f1
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 08 08:37:41 wspbm systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not post comment due to my low rep so please excuse my answer first.

From the [man interfaces.5](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html) syntax should contain stanzas + method.
I have just tried similar config, removing stanzas and methods which ended up with the same error message.

Copy pasted and edited your /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# Configure the primary network interface
# This is the interface facing the internet
# and is in the br0 bridge
auto enp3s0f0
iface enp3s0f0 inet manual

# Configure the interface facing the kid's router
# This is the interface on ingress which has unfiltered 
# traffic and is in the br_parental bridge
auto enp3s0f1
iface enp3s0f1 inet manual

# Configure the other two interfaces to try and avoid errors
auto enp4s0f0
iface enp4s0f0 inet manual

auto enp4s0f1
iface enp4s0f1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports enp3s0f0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0

auto br_parental
iface br_parental inet static
    address 192.168.5.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    # do you want to set gateway?
    bridge_ports enp3s0f1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: @Flip, adding the "inet manual" lines for the physical interfaces appears to have done the trick for me.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Flip, I don't appear to have the ability to do so :(

Answer (score 1):

Just to explicitly write out an answer, the following lines from the /etc/networking/interfaces file were missing that were preventing the networking service from being restarted error free:

```
iface enp3s0f0 inet manual
iface enp3s0f1 inet manual
iface enp4s0f0 inet manual
iface enp4s0f1 inet manual
```

Once those lines were added right after the 'auto' lines for the respective interfaces, the network service could be properly restarted:

```
[root@wspbm]# service networking restart
[root@wspbm]# systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-08-08 16:18:25 MDT; 5min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 4062 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4397 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4390 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4397 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 1.2M
      CPU: 1.177s
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service
           └─4962 /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.br0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.br0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.br0.leases br0

Aug 08 16:18:24 wspbm dhclient[4821]: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0xccaaa745)
Aug 08 16:18:24 wspbm ifup[4397]: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0xccaaa745)
Aug 08 16:18:24 wspbm dhclient[4821]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.17 on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x45a7aacc)
Aug 08 16:18:24 wspbm ifup[4397]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.17 on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x45a7aacc)
Aug 08 16:18:24 wspbm ifup[4397]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.17 from 192.168.1.53
Aug 08 16:18:24 wspbm dhclient[4821]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.17 from 192.168.1.53
Aug 08 16:18:25 wspbm dhclient[4821]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.17 from 192.168.1.53
Aug 08 16:18:25 wspbm ifup[4397]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.17 from 192.168.1.53
Aug 08 16:18:25 wspbm ifup[4397]: bound to 192.168.1.17 -- renewal in 34561 seconds.
Aug 08 16:18:25 wspbm systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
[root@wspbm]#
```